# Oracle Query Optimization Required ( elapsed time = 2.37 sec )

Tags: sql, oracle, performance, oracle10g, query-optimization

Below query is taking time ( 2.37 sec ) to execute. I have Approx 5,00,00 records and 2,00,00 records in FORWARD_INFO and G_PROFILE tables respectively.

I need to optimized this query. It should take ~.20 sec. Can you please suggest.

Using Oracle10g DB.

```
SELECT S_NUM, STATUS, TRANSLATION_NUM, ANN, NOTIFY_ANN, ID, NAME, 
  PROFILE_ID, ANN_ID, RES_PROFILE_ID, R_ANN, RES_ANN_ID 
FROM(
  SELECT CSC.S_NUM,CSC.STATUS, CSC.TRANSLATION_NUM, CSC.ANN, CSC.NOTIFY_ANN, CSC.ID, CGP.NAME, CGP.PROFILE_ID, CGP.ANN_ID, CGP.RES_PROFILE_ID, CGP.R_ANN, CGP.RES_ANN_ID, 
     RANK() OVER(ORDER BY LENGTH(CSC.S_NUM) DESC) RANKING 
  FROM 
    FORWARD_INFO CSC, G_PROFILE CGP 
  WHERE '0120913005' LIKE CSC.S_NUM||'%' AND 
         CGP.NAME LIKE 'ase' ||'%' AND 
         CSC.ACCOUNT_NUMBER=10 AND CSC.ID= CGP.ID AND 
         CSC.ACTIVE = 1 AND CGP.ACTIVE = 1) 
WHERE RANKING = 1 AND 
         ROWNUM = 1;
```

Comment: I don't think anybody could help without at least the DDL of tables and indexes and a basic understanding of the data contained in the tables and the logic of the query.

Comment: Please [edit] your question add the `create table` statements for the tables in question (including all indexs) and the execution plan. [**Formatted text**](http://stackoverflow.com/editing-help#code) please, [no screen shots](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/285551/why-may-i-not-upload-images-of-code-on-so-when-asking-a-question/285557#285557)

Answer (score 0):

After little reformatting

```
SELECT S_NUM, STATUS, TRANSLATION_NUM, 
    ANN, NOTIFY_ANN, ID, NAME, 
    PROFILE_ID, ANN_ID, RES_PROFILE_ID , R_ANN,
    RES_ANN_ID 
FROM
    (SELECT CSC.S_NUM,CSC.STATUS, CSC.TRANSLATION_NUM, CSC.ANN, CSC.NOTIFY_ANN, CSC.ID, 
        CGP.NAME, CGP.PROFILE_ID, CGP.ANN_ID, CGP.RES_PROFILE_ID , CGP.R_ANN, CGP.RES_ANN_ID, 
        RANK() OVER (ORDER BY LENGTH(CSC.S_NUM) DESC) RANKING 
    FROM FORWARD_INFO CSC
        JOIN G_PROFILE CGP ON CSC.ID = CGP.ID 
    WHERE '0120913005' LIKE CSC.S_NUM||'%' 
        AND CGP.NAME LIKE 'ase' ||'%' 
        AND CSC.ACCOUNT_NUMBER = 10          
        AND CSC.ACTIVE = 1 
        AND CGP.ACTIVE = 1) 
WHERE RANKING = 1 
    AND ROWNUM = 1;
```

you see the bottleneck:

```
'0120913005' LIKE CSC.S_NUM||'%' AND CGP.NAME LIKE 'ase' ||'%'
```

You could create Function-Based-Indexes.

```
CREATE INDEX NAME_LIKE_ASE ON G_PROFILE (SUBSTR(NAME, 1, 3));
CREATE INDEX S_NUM_LIKE ON G_PROFILE (S_NUM||'%');
```

Your WHERE condition the would be

```
'0120913005' LIKE CSC.S_NUM||'%' AND SUBSTR(NAME, 1, 3) = 'ase'
```

Then you should have indexes on `FORWARD_INFO.ID` and `G_PROFILE.ID`.

Comment: Shouldn't the S_NUM_LIKE index be created on FORWARD_INFO not G_PROFILE? Also, it would probably help to include other columns in the predicates into the fbi's too

Comment: But in general, even though yours are good advice, we still don't have all the info. What's the most selective criteria? There is already an index on it? What if (for example) the two indexes aren't selective at all, and the OP just wants the few "active" records on a majority of "inactive ones"? The solution could be again a FBI , but on the active column. So, the OP should really give us more info if he wants us to help him achieve a 10x performance gain.

Answer (score -3):

IN WHERE CLAUSE

```
WHERE '0120913005' LIKE 
  CSC.S_NUM||'%' AND CGP.NAME LIKE 'ase' ||'%' AND 
  CSC.ACCOUNT_NUMBER=10 AND CSC.ID= CGP.ID AND 
  CSC.ACTIVE = 1 AND CGP.ACTIVE = 1
```

change the order of conditions like this

```
WHERE CSC.ACTIVE = 1 AND CGP.ACTIVE = 1  AND 
  CSC.ACCOUNT_NUMBER=10 AND CSC.ID= CGP.ID  AND 
 '0120913005' LIKE 
  CSC.S_NUM||'%' AND CGP.NAME LIKE 'ase' ||'%'
```

String comparison takes a lot of costs

Comment: Order of WHERE conditions does not match. The Optimizer may re-arrange them anyway.

Comment: Since oracle is cost-based optimization it will arrange the order on its own